# Failing to copy a folder to /var/www/html/ using cp command

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04, cp

I was trying to copy a folder from home directory to apache2 server root directory i.e., /var/www/html in my Ubuntu 14.04. I was using the following command-

> $ sudo cp *Folder* /var/www/html

And getting following result-

> cp: omitting directory ‘Folder Name’

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for copy folders you must use "-R" option , try it :

```
cp -Rv Folder /var/www/html
```

-R         for copy folders

-v         for see what folders and files are copied

also for more information please run command :

```
man cp
```

Answer (score 2):

This too worked for me: Copying the whole folder.

```
sudo cp -r myFolder/ /var/www/
```